# Static routing between three routers

Tags: router, routing

**Router 0**
Model : TL-WDR4300
Hardware Version : WDR4300 v1 00000000
Firmware Version : 3.14.3 Build 150518 Rel.70901n

**Router 1**
Model : Archer C2
Hardware Version : Archer C2 v1 00000000
Firmware Version : 0.9.1 3.2 v0032.0 Build 151022 Rel.60429n

**Router 2**
Model : TL-WR941ND
Hardware Version : 
Firmware Version :

I would like to connect three routers to each other, in the following way:

## Internet - ISP

**Router 0:**
(WAN Side): 
ISP Provider
Subnet Mask: ISP Provider
(LAN Side)
IP: 192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

**Router 1:**
(WAN Side)
192.168.1.2
255.255.255.0
(LAN Side)
192.168.2.1
255.255.255.0

**Router 2:**
(WAN Side)
192.168.1.3
255.255.255.0
(LAN Side)
192.168.3.1
255.255.255.0

But, the devices conected to each LAN (LAN 0, LAN 1 and LAN 2) cannot see each other. Example, The PC (IP 192.168.2.101) on LAN 1 cannot reache the printer (IP 192.168.1.105)on the LAN 0; and the Smartphone (IP 192.168.3.107) on LAN 2, cannot reache the PC Content on LAN 1.
How I need to set up the routers to do that.

Can you help me? Please.

Thank you.

Comment: How are we supposed to debug your routing problem if you don't share your route tables? Please edit your question to include the route tables from each router.

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't doing plain static routing. You're probably doing NAT (NAPT) gatewaying. NAT blocks incoming connections from the WAN side by default (so things on LAN 0 can't initiate connections to things on LAN 1 and LAN 2 in your setup).

Even if you *are* doing static routing, many service discovery protocols are based on multicasts in an address range that is not supposed to be routed off the current subnet, and many times the software for setting up, say, a new printer, might use a discovery protocol rather than letting you manually type in a static IP address. So even doing plain static routing in a home network is often problematic when you need devices to connect from one subnet to another.

Most home networks are best designed as a single subnet behind a single NAT gateway, with all other Wi-Fi APs acting as simple transparent APs rather than acting as routers or NAT gateways.